# deploying debug app to playbook gives "failure 881 required signatures missing (RDK, AUTHOR)"

Tags: installation, code-signing, blackberry-playbook

I am using Marmalade to build a PlayBook app, but I think my question applies to PlayBook apps in general. I have successfully created a debugtoken.bar file and have installed it on my device. When I go to try to install a built application.bar file on the device, I get:

```
 [execute] "blackberry-deploy.bat -device 192.168.1.114 -password ******* -installApp -package deployments\default\playbook\release\Quote Unquote.bar"
Info: Sending request: Install
Info: Action: Install
Info: File size: 6400334
Info: Installing ...
Info: Processing 6400334 bytes
actual_dname::
actual_id::
actual_version::
result::failure 881 required signatures missing (RDK, AUTHOR)
ERROR: error running blackberry-deploy
***ERROR***
```

Note that this is the Marmalade deploy tool running the standard PlayBook installer.

What I don't understand is: I thought the point of using a debugtoken.bar file was that you could install unsigned apps. I have in fact successfully deployed these unsigned apps using the Marmalade deploy tool just like this. But I was having problems signing the app for distribution, so I went back and did everything from scratch, requested new code signing keys from RIM, made a new debugtoken.bar file and installed it, etc. And now I'm worse off than I was before because I can't even install to the device now.

So again: My understanding is that the point of debugtoken.bar was to be able to deploy to the device before actually signing the application.bar for distribution. So what does this error message even mean?

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question:

For deploying a "debug" build to a device, it's critical to have

```
Application-Development-Mode: true
```

in the MANIFEST.MF within the .bar file.

A stupid mistake, but I'll leave this up in case it helps anyone...

Comment: That's true, but note that you shouldn't ever need to edit the manifest file directly, in case that was your plan.  The blackberry-nativepackager tool takes a -devMode argument that should set that for you.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, part of my problem comes from using Marmalade where it does some stuff for you and you don't use, for instance, the nativepackager directly. In any case, the main thing was just remembering that there was such a setting.

Comment: did you find a solution to automatically set this to true in the mkb file? or do i have to do this every time with my bar file

Comment: It's in the .MF file, not the .mkb file. No, I didn't automate it. It would probably be easy to modify one of the Marmalade python scripts, but no I haven't done it.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look to the QNX deployment plugin "C:\Marmalade\6.1\s3e\deploy\plugins\qnx\qnx.py" I found that 'FOR DEVELOPMENT' option is false if the 'playbook_keystore' is given so I just cleared the signing section on the Marmalade System Deployment Tool and it is not longer trying to sign it